# C# Anchors Passing Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, anchor

I'm trying to create a A href that will take a value to the same page, it will just fill a textbox hidden. It's pretty much for comment threading, and i want to use the Reply A href to generate which reply it's going to. Anyone have any suggestions?

I have tried  but doesn't seem to fill the textbox it just refreshes the page.

Comment: Could you post some code of what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript within the link:

```
<a href="javascript:_callFunction(this)">Do This</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function _callFunction(link) {
     document.getElementById("hiddenID").value = "X";
  }
</script>
```